# list of infrared codes?

Tags: infrared

I have an app that controls an IR emitter and would like to get access to the universe of IR codes.  Is this something that is freely available, or is it a subscription?

(Companies like harmony and logitech have them - just not sure how I get access to it)

(google did not give me anything useful so far)

NOTE - to be clear - I want a list of devices like TVs, DVD players, etc - like the ones that are printed with universal remotes or ones that are downloaded.  However, I want the actual specifications so I can control the IR diode(s).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Im crossing this bridge now and these answers are not very good!

Comment: No - sorry, nver found one.  I think maybe the best option is to add that into the UI somehow so people can upload the codes themselved (like the old CDDB kind of thing)

Answer (score 12):

[LIRC](http://www.lirc.org/) has a [repository of remote controller codes](http://lirc.sourceforge.net/remotes/) where you can find the codes for various manufacturers of infrared remotes.

Comment: that's good.  I just wish it was a little more usable - ideally I would like to have device models, not remote control models, but this is good I think if I can interpret the hex codes.

Comment: Direct download [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/lirc-remotes/code/ci/master/tree/).

Answer (score 2):

Something like [this](http://users.telenet.be/davshomepage/home.htm)?  If the page doesn't load, view the source for other links.  For example, [here](http://users.telenet.be/davshomepage/sony.htm)'s the Sony protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Can use the Megalist in the following link:

http://www.commandfusion.com/wiki2/software/ir-learner/megalist-ir-database

Answer (score 1):

[irdb](https://github.com/probonopd/irdb) ([irdb.tk](http://irdb.tk) is a dead link) contains IR codes for the devices I was looking for.  I used the values given in the [Pronto IR format](https://www.remotecentral.com/features/irdisp2.htm).

Comment: First link is dead.

Comment: @Deanie Link is updated.

Answer (score -1):

For using a raw LED I'd hook a photodiode or phototransistor to an oscilloscope so you can see what's being sent.  I was under the impression that the pulses are serial ascii data, no idea about stuff like baud rate.  Then use a PIC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontrollers or Atmel in a little box with an LED and battery.  Or build it into your favorite armchair.